# How to identify a process that has been cancelled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, wait-types

How can you identify a process that has been cancelled?

for example:

I was running this dynamic sql - via a linked server:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @i int
declare @z int
DECLARE @vCrlf CHAR(2);

SELECT  @vCrlf = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
       ,@Z = COUNT(*) 
       ,@I = 1
   FROM #T1

    SELECT @sql = '
SET IDENTITY_INSERT bocss2.DBO.tblBCataloguePriceSetItem  ON;
INSERT INTO bocss2.dbo.tblBCataloguePriceSetItem(
            [lngCataloguePriceSetItemID]
           ,[lngCataloguePriceSetID]
           ,[strItemNo]
           ,[strTier1]
           ,[strTier2]
           ,[strTier3]
           ,[strTier4]
           ,[strTier5]
           ,[strTier6]
           ,[sintNameStructureID]
           ,[strCurrencyCode]
           ,[decPrice]
           ,[decWasPrice]
           ,[strBCCurrencyCode]
           ,[decBCPrice]
           ,[decBCWasPrice])
SELECT 
            [lngCataloguePriceSetItemID]
           ,[lngCataloguePriceSetID]
           ,[strItemNo]
           ,[strTier1]
           ,[strTier2]
           ,[strTier3]
           ,[strTier4]
           ,[strTier5]
           ,[strTier6]
           ,[sintNameStructureID]
           ,[strCurrencyCode]
           ,[decPrice]
           ,[decWasPrice]
           ,[strBCCurrencyCode]
           ,[decBCPrice]
           ,[decBCWasPrice]
FROM TABLEBACKUPS.DBO._mm_20140324_tblBCataloguePriceSetItem
ORDER BY [lngCataloguePriceSetItemID]'

    BEGIN TRY
        --PRINT (@SQL)
        EXECUTE [SQLBOCSSLON1.DEV.BODEN.LOCAL].[bocss2].[dbo].[sp_executesql] @SQL
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
```

via a LINKED server, 
[SQLBOCSSLON1.DEV.BODEN.LOCAL]

when I realised the OLEDB WAIT_TYPE going to the roof, so I cancelled this query,
copied and paste the script in the REAL server and run it from there.

This is the OLEDB WAIT TYPE:
[image]

This is the picture of cancelling the query via linked server:

[image]

These are the 2 processes that are currently running on the server.
In yellow is the one that I have cancelled.
Wait_type is SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD, but I cannot see any indication (at least not in my query) - that shows me that this is a process that has been cancelled.

How can I achieve that?

The exact query that I am using is here:

[how to find the T-SQL of a sleeping session that is blocking some other process?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111699/how-to-find-the-t-sql-of-a-sleeping-session-that-is-blocking-some-other-process)

and here:

[how to get the information about sleeping processes that are causing blocking?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112237/how-to-get-the-information-about-sleeping-processes-that-are-causing-blocking?lq=1)

[image]